# Add UISlider To UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uislider

Trying to add a UISlider to UINavigationBar.  I have it to where the slider shows, but when trying to change the value, it will not move.  Here is the code in viewWillAppear.  Note that this is on a child view and not the main parent view.

```
UIView *viewofslider = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 40, 30)];
    UISlider *theslider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
    [theslider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [theslider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    theslider.minimumValue = 50.0;
    theslider.maximumValue = 150.0;
    theslider.continuous = YES;
    theslider.value = 100.0;
    [viewofslider addSubview:theslider];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:viewofslider];
```

Comment: Set the view's origin to 0,0, not 160,10. You also need to set the slider's frame to fit properly in it's parent view. Also, why bother with the `UIView`? Just add the `UISlider` to the navbar.

Comment: sounds like your slider is trapped underneath a view that is stacked above it. Hence the reason you can't interact with it. You may need to bring it to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, I think the width of `viewofslider` is too narrow at 40.0, so the touch is not being picked up by the `UISlider`.

If you change the width of `viewofslider` to 100.0 you should be able to interact with it.

However, I agree with rmaddy's comment that you should simply add the slider to the navigation bar, there's no obvious need for the `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add it to `titleView` of view controller's navigation item in `viewWillAppear:`

```
UISlider *theslider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
...
self.navigationItem.titleView = theslider;
```